Is my proof using induction that every connected graph has a spanning tree correct?
I am trying to prove that every connected graph has a spanning subtree.
I tried to do this by induction with the following induction hypothesis on the number of vertices.
P(n):= There exists a spanning subtree for an n vertex connected graph.
P(1) is true.
Assuming P(k).
Let's consider a connected graph,G, of k+1 vertices, then consider the connected subgraph $G_1$ of k vertices. We can use the induction hypothesis to find a spanning tree of $G_1$,let's call it T. Now we consider the node that we took away from G and connect it to a single other node.Let's call this new graph $T_1$
Since T is connected there exists a path between every node in T, therefore if the taken node is v and it's only connected to another node s. Every node in T is connected to v via the path from the node to s plus the edge to v.
Also $T_1$ has no cycles because T is a tree and we only added a leaf.
Is the fact that I removed an arbitrary node correct?

It's not clear what you mean by "the connected subgraph $G_1$ of $n$ vertices".  Is $n$ supposed to be $k$?   ....but even so, If you remove a node from $G$ you might disconnect it.

In any case, the underlying question has been asked many times on this site, here for instance.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

I believe I fixed the errors of the question
